# Initiator disconnected from target during login equallogic san

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-equallogic

I have a Dell Equallogic San and it is being accessed by many VMWare hosts (Esxi v5.1). Today morning I could find an error like

iSCSI login to target "  " failed for the following reason:
Initiator disconnected from target during login

But Just after 10 seconds this error disappeared and now login works fine.

I have checked this particular datastore through VCenter Server, but I was unlucky to find any errors logged there. Can anyone please tell me what is the basic reason for this error and how it can be solved permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is something that seems to be recurring, you should ensure that your VMware hosts are configured according to Dell's best practices recommendations.

The most likely cause would be the iSCSI login timeout value (defaults to 5 seconds, recommended 60 seconds).

See kb.vmware.com/kb/2007829 for more info

Comment: I should also note that the portion of that KB article referencing "Create a highly available VMkernel port" is not applicable to you. Changes made starting in v5.1 eliminate the need to create this extra vmkernel port.